# Huawei 9000 HD Video Terminal

Tags: sip, asterisk, h.264, rtp, sdp

I'm trying to make Huawei 9000 HD Video Terminal MCU work with asterisk.

Huawei's mcu do not transmit any h264 video and refuses to play the video asterisk sends to it.

Sniffing with wireshark I saw the entire sip negotiation ( relevant traces below ) and the MCU simply rejects the video by putting

> m=video 0 RTP/AVP 99

in the 200 OK.

Another issue is that MCU repeatedly sends an INFO request with a proprietary XML body format

> Content-Type: application/media_control_hw+xml

Which asterisk replies with 415 Unsupported Media Type. Is this INFO request essential to start video session ?

I could not find any support from Huawei. Apparently it do not have any usable forum.

Any ideas ? Please help.

Asterisk -> MCU ( INVITE )

> INVITE sip:mcu@192.168.7.59 SIP/2.0
>   Via: SIP/2.0/UDP 192.168.7.227:5060;branch=z9hG4bK25a4a145;rport
>   Max-Forwards: 70
>   From: "danflu-iphonebria" ;tag=as359f0bce
>   To: 
>   Contact: 
>   Call-ID: 646e2b425316ccd349b90eba3cf276de@192.168.7.227:5060
>   CSeq: 102 INVITE
>   User-Agent: Asterisk PBX SVN-branch-1.8-r402000M
>   Date: Tue, 29 Oct 2013 19:23:41 GMT
>   Allow: INVITE, ACK, CANCEL, OPTIONS, BYE, REFER, SUBSCRIBE, NOTIFY, INFO, PUBLISH
>   Supported: replaces, timer
>   Content-Type: application/sdp
>   Content-Length: 348
>
> v=0
>   o=root 1448364882 1448364882 IN IP4 192.168.7.227
>   s=Asterisk PBX SVN-branch-1.8-r402000M
>   c=IN IP4 192.168.7.227
>   b=CT:384
>   t=0 0
>   m=audio 9676 RTP/AVP 8 0 101
>   a=rtpmap:8 PCMA/8000
>   a=rtpmap:0 PCMU/8000
>   a=rtpmap:101 telephone-event/8000
>   a=fmtp:101 0-16
>   a=ptime:20
>   a=sendrecv
>   m=video 8192 RTP/AVP 99
>   a=rtpmap:99 H264/90000
>   a=sendrecv

@@@

MCU -> Asterisk ( 200 OK )

> SIP/2.0 200 OK
>   Via: SIP/2.0/UDP 192.168.7.227:5060;branch=z9hG4bK25a4a145;rport=5060
>   Call-ID: 646e2b425316ccd349b90eba3cf276de@192.168.7.227:5060
>   From: "danflu-iphonebria";tag=as359f0bce
>   To: ;tag=4qda40eh
>   CSeq: 102 INVITE
>   Contact: "mcu"
>   Allow: INVITE,ACK,BYE,CANCEL,UPDATE,OPTIONS,INFO,NOTIFY,PRACK,REFER
>   User-Agent: Huawei ViewPoint9000/9030-Release_11.2.13.26T
>   Content-Length: 245
>   Content-Type: application/sdp
>
> v=0
>   o=huawei 1 0 IN IP4 192.168.7.59
>   s=-
>   c=IN IP4 192.168.7.59
>   b=CT:384
>   t=0 0
>   m=audio 10002 RTP/AVP 8 0 101
>   a=rtpmap:8 PCMA/8000
>   a=rtpmap:0 PCMU/8000
>   a=rtpmap:101 telephone-event/8000
>   a=fmtp:101 0-15
>   a=sendrecv
>   **m=video 0 RTP/AVP 99  **

@@@

MCU -> Asterisk INFO request

> INFO sip:danflu-iphonebria@192.168.7.227:5060 SIP/2.0
>   Via: SIP/2.0/UDP 192.168.7.59:5060;branch=z9hG4bKlc4dje4ajgjh4lpjgjfca2lfj
>   Call-ID: 646e2b425316ccd349b90eba3cf276de@192.168.7.227:5060
>   From: ;tag=4qda40eh
>   To: "danflu-iphonebria";tag=as359f0bce
>   CSeq: 2 INFO
>   Contact: "mcu"
>   Max-Forwards: 70
>   Content-Length: 455
>   Content-Type: application/media_control_hw+xml
>
> <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
>   <media_control xmlns="http://www.huawei.com/media-control" version="1.0">
>   <cap equ_type="term">
>   <anti_packet_loss>
>   <protocol>h264
>   </anti_packet_loss>
>   <anti_packet_loss2.0>
>   <protocol>h264
>   <stream_type>video_amc
>   </anti_packet_loss2.0>
>   <cisco_tip_cap>
>   <stream_type>video_amc
>   </cisco_tip_cap>
>   <arq_cap>
>   <media_type>video
>   </arq_cap>
>   </cap>
>   </media_control>

Answer (score 1):

Disable on asterisk any codec except this one.

Yes, sure, SINGLE!!! VIDEO!!! CODEC IN SDP is essential for setup. MCU just not offer other choices, asterisk say it can't accept MCU's choice.

P.S. this is not programming question, post in admin support or contact vendor.

Comment: Thanks +1. Its already that way. Apparently it works when direct calling Ekiga softphone.Trying to contact vendor...